# Dynamic Dependent Select Box using Ajax and PHP not working in materialize js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, materialize

In my application, I am using `Dynamic Dependent Select Box` using `Ajax` and `PHP`. My website template is constructed using `materialize js`. In my console it successfully receive the `values` on `Doctor Name` in my application, but isn't load into the `doctor name select box`. With removing `materialize js` and `materialize css` it working fine.

Here is the code:

```
         <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="form_apt">
         <center>   <h2>Request an Appointment</h2>  </center>  <br><br>                    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Doctor Specilization:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">

                    <?php
        function load(){ 
           include('phpquery/dbconnection.php');
            $output='';
            $sql="SELECT * from doctorspecilization";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $output.='<option value="'.$row["specilization"].'">'.$row["specilization"].'</option>';
          }
              return $output;
             }
        ?>

            <select name="doctorspecilization" id="doctorspecilization">
            <option value="">Select Specilization</option> 
             <?php echo load();   ?>

                  </select>
                  <span id="doctorspecilization-info" class="info text-danger"></span><br />

                    </div>
                </div> 


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Doctor :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9" class="select">
                        <select name="doctorname" id="doctorname">
                    <option value="">Select Doctor</option>                                     
                  </select>
                    </div>
                </div> 


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Appointment Date:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Enter your education">
                        <span id="date-info" class="info text-danger"></span><br />
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="form-group mar-bot-0">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <i class="waves-effect waves-light light-btn waves-input-wrapper" style=""><input type="button" value="APPLY NOW" id="apply" name="apply" class="waves-button-input"></i>
                    </div>
                </div><br>
                <center>  <div id="success_mes" class="text text-success">    </div>  </center> <br>

            </form>
```

Here is the`Ajax`:

```
<script>


        //    start query
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#doctorspecilization').change(function () {

var doc_spec_id=$(this).val();

$.ajax({
            url: "phpquery/fetch_doctor_name.php", // Url to which the request is send
            method: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: {doc_spec_id:doc_spec_id  },
            dataType:"text",

            success: function (data) {
                $("#doctorname").html(data);

            }

        });


    });
</script>
```

I don't know where I went wrong. Any help may highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#1 Materialize select needs [initializing](https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization)**

I can't see any initialization in your code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
```

**#2 Select added dynamically will need initializing**

```
success: function (data) {
                $("#doctorname").html(data);
                $('select').formSelect();

         }
```

https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization

Comment: Thanks for the promptly response. Please indicate me where I need to paste the code that you provided????

Comment: So it depends on your project set up. I work in Wordpress so I serve jQuery, then materialize.js, and then my custom js - and the initialization goes in the custom js file, after materialize. Certain Materialize components need this to work. And if you add stuff to the dom after the fact, materialize doesn't know they are there

Comment: I used `$('select').material_select();`, but if I select two times only load to the select box. When I changed the value on select box it won't changed...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. It's hard to debug without seeing a live example. Why are you using $('select').material_select, instead of $('select').formSelect();? You could try being more specific, so $(#doctorname").formSelect();